# MongoDB find documents with a field not empty, IF EXISTS

Tags: mongodb, typeorm, robo3t

I want to be able to query documents having a specific field's value not empty, if the field is present. Normally I'd do something like:

```
client_comment: { '$exists': true, '$ne': null },
'$expr': { '$eq': [ { "$ne": "$client_comment" }, null ] },
```

The thing is, some of the records have this field, some of them don't... and some of them are empty strings. I want to exclude those who have `client_comment` value as empty strings but I don't know how do I do that.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0b1b094dfee4f3a2f4f62a"),
    "name" : "Jane Doe",
    "email" : "john_doe@gmail.com",
    "status" : "done",
    "created_date" : ISODate("2021-10-03T19:38:56.462Z"),
    "updated_date" : ISODate("2021-10-03T19:38:56.462Z"),
}
   
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0b1b094dcee4f3a2f4f62a"),
    "name" : "Lorem Ipsum",
    "email" : "test@gmail.com",
    "status" : "done",
    "created_date" : ISODate("2021-10-03T19:38:56.462Z"),
    "updated_date" : ISODate("2021-10-03T19:38:56.462Z"),
    "client_comment" : "Lorem ipsum",
}

// Exclude this record from the result
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0b1b094dfef4f3a2f4f62a"),
    "name" : "John Doe",
    "email" : "jane.doe@gmail.com",
    "status" : "done",
    "created_date" : ISODate("2021-10-03T19:38:56.462Z"),
    "updated_date" : ISODate("2021-10-03T19:38:56.462Z"),
    "client_comment" : "",
}
```

Comment: Try `.find({ client_comment: { $exists: true, $eq: {$size: 0} } })`

Comment: doesn't return any records

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query1

- find solution
- keep document if field is `missing` or its not empty string

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62856f6b853f039c69b0f8e3)

```js
find({"$or": 
 [{"client_comment": {"$exists": false}}, {"client_comment": {"$ne": ""}}]})
```

Query2

- aggregate solution
- keep document if field is `missing` or its not empty string

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70215812)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match": 
    {"$expr": 
      {"$or": 
        [{"$eq": [{"$type": "$client_comment"}, "missing"]},
         {"$ne": ["$client_comment", ""]}]}}}])
```